# Explain sed command: df -P . | sed -n '$s/[[:blank:]].*//p'

Tags: shell, sed

```
$    df -P .
Filesystem     1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5   440667528 368468280  49744876      89% /
```

I know the current directory disk info is like this.
But I really confused 'sed' command.

```
$ df -P . | sed -n '$s/[[:blank:]].*//p'
/dev/nvme0n1p5
```

like `$s/[[:blank:]].*//p` this string meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed -n '$s/[[:blank:]].*//p'`

The `-n` tells sed not to print any lines unless specified with a `p` command.  The `$` matches the last line of the input.  The command `s/[[:blank:]].*//p` replaces a blank and all remaining characters with the empty string.  The trailing `/p` flag is an instuction to print the line after the substitution.  In total, the sed command just prints the first word of the last line of the input stream.

This could be written more readably as: `awk 'END{print $1}'`, but more likely the intent of the command is `awk 'NR>1{print $1}'`, which could be done in `sed` with `sed -e 1d -e 's/[[:blank:]].*//'`

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun little command to look through, here's what I found.

I relied on the [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) quite a bit and running your `sed` command in my terminal to break down what the `sed` request is doing.

### Let's take it piece by piece:

`df -P .` shows you the amount of free disk space in a STDOUT format, [df man page resource](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1p-df/), which you indicated you already understood.

`df -P . | sed` will pipe the output of `df` to the `sed` command, here's a resource with more examples of the `|` [pipe command](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pipes-command-line-linux).

`df -P . | sed -n` the `-n` option will suppress printing the pattern space at the end of the filter cycle, I found [this explanation from gnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html#Execution-Cycle) helped me understand this option better:

> When the end of the script is reached, unless the -n option is in use, the contents of pattern space are printed out to the output stream, adding back the trailing newline if it was removed.

`df -P . | sed -n '$s/regexp/replacement/'` from the [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> `s/regexp/replacement/` Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space. If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.

and

> `$` Match the last line.

So for example, `sed -n $s/regexp/replacement/` in plain English is saying "In the last line of the input, find `regexp` and replace it with `replacement`.

Finally, `[:blank:]` [matches spaces and tabs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html), `.*` will match any character, and the `p` option at the end of `s/regexp/replacement/p` tells `sed` to output the matched line to the terminal.

### Putting it all together:

`df -P . | sed -n '$s/[[:blank:]].*//p'`

1. Pipe the amount of disk space in stdout format into `sed`
2. `sed` will attempt to match this expression: `[[:blank:]].*` in the last line of the piped input
3. If there is a match, replace the matched tab or space and all characters after with nothing
4. Print out what remains of the matched line

That was probably more than you were looking for and I hope it helps give you some options to explore exactly what's happening with this command.